# How to search for the exact word in the parentheses using rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I want to know how to find the exact word in the parenthesis and not words that include the word that has been searched. For example, if I trying to search for Carbon Monoxide `[CO]` and if I searched CO I want my results to only show Carbon Monoxide `[CO]` and not like Carbon Dioxide `[CO2]`.

So far I have,

```
where("lower(gas_analyte) LIKE lower(?)", "%#{gas_analyte}%")
```

Comment: You can use regex in ActiveRecord queries, In your example, you can do
`
.where("gas_analyte ~* ?", '\[CO\]$')
`
SO doesnt format my regex correctly, you can see it here https://regexper.com/#%5C%5BCO%5C%5D%24
Unfortunately having `'\[#{gas_analyte}\]$'` didn't work for me, that is something you'll have to search and check. Hence why I added this as a comment

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't use like query in this case!.You can use **where** condition which is the result of filtering the current relation according to the conditions in the arguments.
it will return exact params matching records..

```
where(gas_analyte:gas_analyte)
```

**Ilike** it returns something matching records of ur params..

Comment: Thank you but it is not working. I think it is because I'm only trying to get the content inside the bracket

Comment: Ohh sorry..can you show me your records in table?and what is your trying to achieve?

Comment: sensors = sensors.joins(setup_variable: :gas_analytes).where("lower(gas_analytes.gas)[/\[(.*?)\]/, 1] LIKE lower(?)", "#{gas_analyte}"). This is what I have but it doesn't work. So I want to see if the searched content equals the content in the bracket by doing [/\[(.*?)\]/, 1], but it doesn't work. So is there something similar I can do only match the content in the bracket.

Comment: @Gases = ['Carbon Dioxide [CO2]','Ethanol [CH3CH2OH]', 'Carbon Monoxide [CO]'] is the variable that holds the gases